# Creating a bitmask of a Texture

Tags: libgdx

I am using a TextureAtlas to load TextureRegions and I need to generate a bitmask for every loaded Texture. I would like to extend the gdx code to generate that bitmask. So i need to find the part of code before the texture is loaded to the GPU but its accesable from the CPU. Does anybody got a hint for me?

(That bitmask should tell me later if a pixel was transparent or not. I think this could be a good solution for hit detection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TextureAtlas.load`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.java#L230) calls the [`Texture` file constructor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java#L129) which uses [`FileTextureData`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FileTextureData.java#L39).  Eventually [`prepare`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FileTextureData.java#L58) will be invoked on the `FileTextureData` object.  This loads a new [`Pixmap`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.java#L135) with the file contents.  The `Pixmap` will be backed by a [`Gdx2DPixmap`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Gdx2DPixmap.java) and its (native) `load` method will actually read the bytes out of the file.

The `Pixmap` is the visible object that contains CPU-mutable bytes.

Instead of trying to modify the Libgdx texture loading system to add your bitmask textures, you might try this approach: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=515 (generates a `Pixmap` from a `TextureRegion`).  Its a little less efficient at run-time, but the code is quick and simple.  Plus you don't have to make a bitmap mask for the entire atlas page, but can do masks for individual textures.

Comment: Thank you! I will use this approach to generate the bitmasks and store them in a file. The reason why I dont want to use Pixmap directly is that I want to reduce memory usage. I dont need color values but just a boolean. And I would like to reduce the bitmask resolution because it does not have to be very accurate.